# Downloading Google spreadsheet to csv - csv.writer adding a delimiter after every character

Tags: python, google-sheets

Going off the code from here: https://gist.github.com/cspickert/1650271  Instead of `print`ing, I want to write to a csv file.

Added this at the bottom:

```
# Request a file-like object containing the spreadsheet's contents
csv_file = gs.download(ss)

# Write CSV object to a file
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(csv_file)
```

Maybe I need to do a transform to csv_file before I can write?

Comment: Why not just write csv_file directly to a file?

Comment: How do I do that?  I'm new and learning.  The last bit was the result of ~1 hour of Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects) says that:

> csvwriter.writerows(rows) Write all the rows parameters  (a list of
>   row objects as described above) to the  writer’s file object,
>   formatted according to the current dialect.

Since csv_file is a file-like object, you need to convert it to a list of rows:

```
rows = csv.reader(csv_file)
a.writerows(rows)
```

Or, better yet, you can simply write to file:

```
csv_file = gs.download(ss)
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(csv_file.read())
```